# foreach not scaling in bootstrapping when number of selected observations is large

Tags: r, foreach, bootstrapping, doparallel

I have an interesting problem with bootstrapping in R using the `foreach` package. I have an algorithm that works as follows

Given `R`, the number of repetitions in the bootstrap and `N_B`, the number of observations to use in the bootstrap, and the data set I'm using, `flights`.

1. In each iteration, select `N_B` observations from `flights` with replacement
2. Run the regression `lm(arr_delay ~ log_distance, data = flights_subset)` and get the coefficient on `log_distance`
3. Calculate the standard deviation of the `R` different betas across the regressions.

I am using the R package `foreach` to do this. I have an unparallelized and parallelized versions.

The problem: The relative performance of the `%dopar` version of `foreach` depends *heavily* on the observations-per-iteration `N_b`.

Using a fork cluster with 5 nodes, and  `N_B = 9000`, I get the following timing

```
Timings
=======
Analytic time:  0.049 
Unparallel foreach time:  6.981 
Parallel time 2.089
```

But when I bump `N_B` up to 20000, instead I get *no* performance improvement from parallelization.

```
Timings
=======
Analytic time:  0.053 
Unparallel foreach time:  21.88 
Parallel time 18.873
```

Am I running into GC issues by allocating too much inside the hot loop? If so, how can I diagnose this?

Thank you!

A full MWE is below

```
library(tidyverse)
library(nycflights13)
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)

#######################################

# Randomly draw samples fromyour data set n_B times.
# Each new dataset has n_B rows.

# Obtail OLS estimator from the samples obtained
# in Step 1

# Repeat Step 1 and 2 for R number of times. Get 
# empirical distribution of beta_hat

# Do this for arr_delay ~ log(distance) in flights

# Do it for parallelized and unparallelize methods.
# Check the speed for both methods.

########################################

DEBUG = TRUE

get_beta = function(flights, N_b) {
  sub_data = sample_n(flights, N_b, replace = TRUE)
  m = lm(arr_delay ~ log_distance, data = sub_data)
  coef(m)[2]
}

get_se_analytic = function(flights) {
  m = lm(arr_delay ~ log_distance, data = flights)
  se = sqrt(diag(vcov(m)))[[2]]
}


get_se_unparallel_foreach = function(R, flights, N_b) {
  betas = foreach(
    icount(R), 
    .combine = 'c',
    .export = c(
      "get_beta"),
      .packages = "dplyr") %do% {
    beta = get_beta(flights, N_b)
  }

  sd(betas)
}

get_se_parallel = function(R, flights, N_b) {
  betas = foreach(
    icount(R), 
    .combine = 'c',
    .export = c(
      "get_beta"),
      .packages = "dplyr") %dopar% {
    beta = get_beta(flights, N_b)
  }

  sd(betas)
}

main = function() {
  R = 1000
  flights = nycflights13::flights %>% 
    sample_frac(.1) %>%
    mutate(log_distance = log(distance)) %>%
    select(arr_delay, log_distance)

  N_b = 20000

  # Set up the cluster
  cl = makeForkCluster(5)
  registerDoParallel(cl)

  time_analytic = system.time({se_analytic = get_se_analytic(flights)})
  time_unparallel_foreach = system.time({se_unparallel_foreach = get_se_unparallel_foreach(R, flights, N_b)})
  time_parallel = system.time({se_parallel = get_se_parallel(R, flights, N_b)})

  cat("Standard errors\n")
  cat("===============\n")
  cat("Analytic standard error: ", se_analytic, "\n")
  cat("Unparallel foreach standard error: ", se_unparallel_foreach, "\n")
  cat("Parallel standard error", se_parallel, "\n")

  # Close the cluster
  stopCluster(cl)

  ses = c(
    se_analytic,
    se_unparallel_foreach,
    se_parallel)

  # Test for correctness 
  correct = all(abs(ses - se_analytic) < .2 * se_analytic)

  if(correct == FALSE && DEBUG == FALSE) {
    stop("The standard errors are not close enough")
  }
  cat("\n")
  cat("Timings\n")
  cat("=======\n")
  cat("Analytic time: ", time_analytic[[3]], "\n")
  cat("Unparallel foreach time: ", time_unparallel_foreach[[3]], "\n")
  cat("Parallel time", time_parallel[[3]], "\n")
}

main()
```

Comment: Can you test, instead of using `system.time`, with `microbenchmark::microbenchmark` with parameter `times = 50` or more (while affordable) to get a better indicator?

Comment: I can do it tomorrow, but it seems unlikely this is a benchmarking error. It's consistent across tests. Plus it will take along time to run that benchmark.